# Making a precise angle with the lerp

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, smoothing

How can I roll an object in a precise angle with the lerp
For example, 90 = 90, not like 90 = 89.9982

```
Vector3  Angle = new Vector3(FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles.x, 90f,
  FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles.z);

FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles,
  Angle,Time.deltaTime );
```

I have used this code, but don't get the exact angle (90 = 89.9982). Is there a way that this function will create a precise angle?

Answer (score -1):

[*Vector3.Lerp*](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) is a method which interpolates linearly between two Vector3.

To keep it simple, the parameter *t* [0..1] is a cursor between the *from* value and the *to* value.

- If *t* is equal to 0, the method will return *from*.
- If *t* is equal to 1, the method will return *to*.
- If *t* is equal to 0.5, the method will return the position in the exact middle of *from* and *to*.

Here, you assign the returned value to *from*. So it will rotate "smoothly" your object, but *t* (*Time.deltaTime*) will probably never be equal to 1, so *from* will just converge to *to* without reaching it.

So a fix could be:

```
float t = 0f;

while (t < 1f) { // for example
    Vector3 initial = FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 Angle = new Vector3(FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles.x, 90f , FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles.z);

    FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(initial, Angle, t);

    t += Time.deltaTime;
    yield return null; // if you are in a coroutine
}
```

It will linearly rotate your object.

If you want to do this smoothly:

```
Vector3 Angle = new Vector3(FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles.x, 90f , FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles.z);
float speed = 10f;

while (Vector3.Distance(FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles, Angle) > 0.1f) { // for example
    FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles, Angle, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    yield return null; // if you are in a coroutine
}
// So it will leave the loop when it's very close (0.1f) to *to* (here Angle)
FirstGizmo.transform.eulerAngles = Angle;
```

Comment: You shouldn't `lerp` euler angles. Convert that to a Quaternion and `SLERP` it.